# Prevent the jQuery Elastic plugin from resizing the textarea down on click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

anyone using the [jQuery Elastic plugin](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/) around here?

Pretty handy but I just don't find a way to prevent the script from slightly resizing the height of the textarea down once you click out of it. Just make the test: make the area grow by typing something and click out of the textarea.

It's frustrating and gives a bad experience since I have a button at the bottom of my textarea which also moves then. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add mouseout to the event binding:

```
 $textarea.bind('blur mouseout',function(){
```

on line 140.

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize it using `$('#container').elastic().trigger('blur')`

This will run the commands that are run after a blur event, resizing the textbox.

Comment: it just triggers the event on page initialization, but i launch another  blur event when i'm done typing and leave the textarea so it doesn't work...

Comment: what i thought is: you problem is that it auto size even if you dont change the text, and that move things around. so i'll just move things as a first thing, so the user wont notice it moving later.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and after searching for a long time i came up with a solution. 
here is what you need to change in the Jquery Elastic JS file.

Find the following Line.

```
minheight    = parseInt ............
```

and change it with this line.

```
minheight    = parseInt($textarea.css('height'),5) || lineHeight*2,
```

This should solve the problem of clicking outside of the textarea and resizing the box.